# Programming event logic around bluetooth-beacons

Tags: java, android, events, collections, logic

I have a beacon and want to act every time a user enters and exit one of the beacons, 
the available number of beacons is unlimited.

I get an a continuos update events about which and how many beacons is in the area I'm standing at.

the code looks kind of:

```
private void rangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<IBeacon> iBeacons) {
    if (iBeacons.size() > 0) {

    }
}
```

How do I define the logic so that I can send an event every time a new unique beacon is found and every time I lose a beacon?

Is it a good idea to have an array with old beacons and the current beacons and compare them?

I have a UIDID on every beacon so I'll know if it's unique or not.

The method above is called x amount of times per minute.

Comment: You probably should not use a distinct region UUID for each beacon, as although that works on Android where the entire advertising packet is arbitrary data, it will make any future iOS version of your system difficult once you exceed the iOS API limit of 20 UUIDs at once. Rather, use a consistent UUID for all of your beacons, and vary the major and minor number.

Comment: I'm implementing this on Android, so I'm just given the id and the other ino from the beacon (I have zero control over it).